# Django manager.py sql creates empty file

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to run my first Django application with sqlite3 database. When I run `python manage.py sql my_app`, it outputs the SQL queries, but the sqlite file is empty. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command just prints the sql statements. If you want to create the schema in the sqlite file, run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

If you are trying to export the sql statements to a text file:

```
python manage.py sql my_app > my_file.sql
```